# Fetching Gravatar

Tags: gravatar

How can I fetch anyone’s gravatar image?

I need to show users gravatar image on a custom profile page that am making.

I have so far integrated the option of Facebook Profile Pic (which automatically gets grabbed) and also am allowing user to assign his/her own photo (on wish).

What I need to do is, if person do not comes from FB, then maybe his email or something should be used to see if he/she has a gravatar, if yes then display it. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`get_avatar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar). The following example prints an avatar in 96 px, assuming that you have the user id stored in `$user_id`, and prints a fallback `user.png` if no such user or image could be found.

```
echo get_avatar($user_id, 96, get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/user.png');
```

Comment: i will implement it asap, and will revert back. thanks for the reply.